# Automatic numbers superscripting in OS X Maverick and Pages 5

Tags: macos, pages

Is there any way to setup automatic superscripting in OS X Mavericks and Pages 5 (i.e 1st => 1<sup>st</sup>.

Is there a 3<sup>th</sup> party plugin that implements that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet.  I would recommend staying with Pages 4 if that feature is important.  A workaround might be to add what you need to the Text Substitution section of system prefences using Unicode superscripts, but it may not work or look that great.

ᵃ ᵇ ᶜ ᵈ ᵉ ᶠ ᵍ ʰ ⁱ ʲ ᵏ ˡ ᵐ ⁿ ᵒ ᵖ ʳ ˢ ᵗ ᵘ ᵛ ʷ ˣ ʸ ᶻ